# Has it a more "beautiful" solution for a generic determination?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code which works but I think it may not beoptimal because in theory compiler can determinate a generic type from the calling child class. Is there a way to rewrite this code such that I do not need to provide the `ChildType` generic type parameter?

```
public abstract class Test<ChildType, T> where ChildType: Test<ChildType, T>, new()
{
    public T Field { get; set; }

    public static ChildType Get(T field) {
        return new ChildType() { Field = field };
    }
}

public class ChildTest: Test<ChildTest, string>
{
}

// Call sample
var child = ChildTest.Get("test");
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't think the code as-is will work, since the `Get` method is called like a static method, but it is an instance method.

Comment: Can I rewrite it so to I don't need to specify a generic type in a child class? Because it will be always a child type.

Comment: What is "child class" and "child type" in this context? What does or doesn't this code do, and what part specifically do you want to make "more elegant"?

Comment: provide declaration of class `Test` with one generic argument

Comment: @Maarten, you're right! I mistaped when I wrote it.

Comment: @Шах Also `where ChildType: Test<ChildType>` is not valid since there are 2 generic arguments.

Comment: @Maarten, thank you, I fixed. Just I wrote it from my phone.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you want. Are you saying that you want to be able to declare `Test` with only the `T` type parameter? If so the simple answer is no because it needs to know about the class that it is creating. If your question is something else then please clarify what you are wanting to try to do (possibly with some pseudo code of what you want to be able to write)...

Comment: @Chris, no-no, you got right. Thank you! I wanna know if it's the single way to declare so class or C# has more simple solution to get the calling class type.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I argreed with you but I can't authorize on my work computer because it has the limited Internet access, unfortunately.

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully make it clearer. Can you verify that I've not changed the intent of your question?

Comment: @Chris, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that it is pretty much required for the `Test` class to have the `ChildType` generic type specified. You *could* use reflection to get the current type and instantiate an instance of it but reflection is generally best avoided.

To see why consider the `Test` class on its own and in particular this line:

```
return new ChildType() { Field = field };
```

That line requires two pieces of information. First it needs to know what the actual type of `ChildType` is. You can't hardcode it because it can of course vary. The second piece of information it needs is to know it can create a new object of this type in this way.

Both of these pieces of information are provided through the generic type parameter and the generic constraint which is why it is required.

Comment: Would also note that It is a good idea to use the TChildType, TFieldType notation intead ChildType and T when declaring the generic types for the abstract class. Because ChildType refers to a class (most of the time people would understand it so) and not generic type.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! I really glad that at least someone could get me) Because I am not so good know C# and try to improve my skills to write a good code.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen: That is an excellent point (though I would personally go with `TChild` and `TField` myself) but not directly relevant to the question so I'm happy to leave it in comments.

Comment: @Chris true, TChildType declares the type twice ;)

Comment: @Шах: Glad we got to the bottom of it. :)

Comment: =) I'm too. Just I should improve my English level.

Comment: @Шах: Your english is much better than any other language I speak. ;-)

Comment: @Chris, Thank you!)